# Comparator and PriorityQueue

Tags: java, comparator

```
        int points[][] = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, {3,3},{5,-1},{-2,4}}, k = 2;
        Queue<int[]> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> ((b[0] * b[0] + b[1] * b[1]) - (a[0] * a[0] + a[1] * a[1])));
        for (int[] e : points) {
            pq.add(e);`
             if (pq.size() > k)
                pq.remove();
        }
```

Can anybody please explain to me the working of this code?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never had the need to use `PriorityQueue` so I can't authoritatively comment on the above method of achieving the desired goal.

It seems to me that adding and removing in a loop is not very efficient.  By reversing the `Comparator` (instead of `(a,b)->` use `(b,a)->`) the same result could have been achieved doing the following.

```
int points[][] = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, {3,3},{5,-1},{-2,4}}, k = 2;
Queue<int[]> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((b,a) -> ((b[0] * b[0] + b[1] * b[1]) - (a[0] * a[0] + a[1] * a[1])));

for (int[] p : points) {
   pq.add(p);
}

while (k-- > 0) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pq.poll()));
}
```

One observation is that for extremely large arrays of data, the intermittent removal of items would keep the `PriorityQueue` size to a minimum.

Comment: Yes, this would be a better way than inserting and removing.Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

The code using the PriorityQueue to order int[], only pick the top2.
the comparator function is:

```java
(a, b) -> ((b[0] * b[0] + b[1] * b[1]) - (a[0] * a[0] + a[1] * a[1])) //smaller item will be sort first
```

for example: { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, they'll be equal, {3,3},{5,-1}, {5,-1} will be bigger.

```java
for (int[] e : points) {
            pq.add(e); // put the int[] into the queue, queue will sort all items
             if (pq.size() > k) 
                pq.remove(); // if the size of the queue exceed, remove the last item in the queue (the more big item)
        }
```

The result of the code will be the top 2 smallest. {1,0} and {0,1}